# Getting url after redirect from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have the following Java code:

```
        URL url = new URL(destUrl);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        c.connect();
        String location = c.getHeaderField("Location");
        c.disconnect();
```

destUrl does a redirect, and I get the URL that it redirected to and put in the string location.  That's really the whole point...I just need to know the URL that gets redirected to.

The code above works great, but I now need to port this to JavaScript or jQuery for a Chrome extension I'm writing.  I've tried numerous methods but so far haven't been successful.

What's the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: destURL,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        var location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
    }
});
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried a very similar approach, but that gives " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.  I tried changing it to jsonp, as that's a recommended work around, but that gives the error Unexpected token < (probably because it's not json, it's html).

Comment: Ok, got it working by putting permissions in the manifest for that domain.  but "Location" is null for the xhr.  Other headers are there though.

Comment: further research showed that the reason location is null is because the redirect has occurred and location is null in that condition.  Any other ideas?